# Why does sink leak when clogged but doesn't during normal operation - and how to fix?

Tags: leak, sink

Problem:
Kitchen sink leaks only when there is a backup/clog in the main sewer line. Otherwise, during normal operation: dishwasher, food processor, cleaning dishes, there are no issues.

Question: How do I fix the problem if I can't tell if it is not leaking at all during normal operation?

History: I recently remodeled and went from two basin to one basin. The previous plumbing had a 2x double-wye for a total of three p-traps, each servicing one of the drains and the dishwasher separately. I cut off one of the wyes, reaming the old PVC out, capped it by cementing the cap to the reamed out chamber, and routed everything through the remaining p-trap.

When I checked my work when it was still fresh - there were no leaks. But when there was a recent clog in my main sewer - the setup leaked. The leak was where I attached the cap to the wye as well as the compression fitting from the disposal outlet to the p-trap. [image]

Comment: With a clogged drain, you have water sitting in the pipes, so a small leak at a leaky joint will show better.  Unclog pipes the water flows though fast and a small leak does not show.  There is a leak at the joints/not put together quite right, but close.

Comment: @crip659 Is the solution to simple cut away the wye - use a <https://www.pvcfittingsonline.com/3-schedule-40-pvc-pipe-extender-s0301-30.html#> pipe extender and rebuild the p-trap to the disposal or was to add sealant (tape, etc.) to the seams?

Comment: It is low pressure, so might get by with tightening the top joint and applying some silicon caulking to the wye.  If it does not work can always rebuild, but I think they are tiny leaks of a few drops, not a gusher.

Comment: Not a gusher - but still significant enough to fill the green catch basin below. I'll add silicon caulking and see what can be done.

Comment: Goop applied to the outside will hardly ever work; get rid of the wye, or replace it with one that has a proper threaded plug (for future service access). Slip-joint connections often need to be snugged up with a wrench...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, please explain "be snugged up with a wrench" did you mean seat it all the way in with a wrench?

Comment: @Bluebird he means you may need some extra leverage to get the slip nut tighter than you can get it by hand.  What is that black thing between your GD and your blue circle?  Looks like some kind of accordion connector???

Comment: Yeah - it came with the GD.

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Jimmy Fix-it's advice and cut off the wye. I used a https://www.homedepot.com/p/Fernco-2-in-x-1-1-2-in-DWV-Flexible-PVC-Coupling-P1056-215/100013986 instead of reaming out the old pipe or using a pipe extender. The coupling was faster and in my opinion - removable incase I needed to clean out the drain after-the-fact.[image]